# Adding new field in Customer type Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm very beginner in Hybris. I need to add in Hybris Customer Type a new field/property of String type. This field should appear in the backoffice in the **User / Customers / General / Essential** column(figure 1).
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FQC7.png)
How can I add it? Through the Impex?

I can only add a field to the properties of the Customer type (through the extensionname-items.xml) (figure 2). 
[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OThpz.png)

Answer (score 1):

To customize backoffice, you need to first create your custom extension using ybackoffice template.

Check [Creating a Custom Backoffice Extension](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8bd2f59e86691014859ba68181c14710.html)

Once you successfully creates extension, you should get yourextension-backoffice-config.xml file generated automatically inside resources folder.

There are multiple editors available OOTB. Check editor-area, create-wizard, base, simple-search, advanced-search, listview etc in platformbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml or any existing *-backoffice-config.xml. You will get an idea how to define these configuration for any type.

At this time, you are more interested in looking Customer type configuration. Check the below configuration in platformbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml

`<context merge-by="type" parent="User" type="Customer" component="editor-area">`

```
OR
```

`<context component="create-wizard" type="Customer">`

The first one is used to edit type instance and later one is used to create new type instance in backoffice.

Backoffice also provide flexibility to use **merge-by** context tag which helps you to merge the configuration while defining in different extension.

To customize Customer Type in editor area. Do like this in yourextension-backoffice-config.xml

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="User" type="Customer" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea name="">
        <editorArea:essentials>
            <editorArea:essentialSection name="hmc.essential">
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="newAttribute"/>                    
            </editorArea:essentialSection>
        </editorArea:essentials>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
```

To customize Customer Type in create-wizard..

```
<context merge-by="type parent="User" type="Customer" component="create-wizard">
    <wz:flow id="CustomerWizard" title="create.title(ctx.TYPE_CODE)">
        <wz:prepare id="custPrepare">
            <wz:initialize property="newCust" type="ctx.TYPE_CODE"/>
        </wz:prepare>
        <wz:step id="step1" label="create.customer.essential.label" sublabel="create.customer.essential.sublabel">
            <wz:content id="step1.content">
                <wz:property-list root="newCust">
                    <wz:property qualifier="newAttribute" type="java.lang.String"/>                     
                </wz:property-list>
            </wz:content>
        </wz:step>  
      </wz:flow>
</context>
```

There is also a very easy step to check existing configuration in Backoffice. Login with admin/nimda and go to Application Orchestrator mode by pressing F4 button. Then click on show conckpit-config.xml at upper left corner.